# menu accordion with toggle button

Tags: angular, typescript

In fact, when I click on the menu, for example the `administration` rubric

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGeGI.png)

I click on the toggle button

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKkfU.png)

The togge button is actived

[step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoecq.png)

I click again on the button toggle

[step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TKpM.png)

Here is my problem, there is an empty line `<li>` added.

[step5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCChK.png)

How can I remove this empty line?

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ active: showSideBar }">
    <div class="logo-details">
        <span class="logo_name">
          <img class="logo_dashboard" src="assets/images/logo_FR.gif" style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey">
      </span>
    </div>
    <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
            <ng-container>
                <div class="menu" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
                    <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="submenu" #submenu [ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' }">
                    <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
                        <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }}"> {{ submenu.name }} </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<section class="home-section">
    <nav>
        <div class="sidebar-button">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn" (click)="toggleSideBar()"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-summary-container">
                <span class="user">Utilisateur:  </span>

                <span class="last-connection">La dernière connexion est le :
     
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

The code is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jrmnan?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html).

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an empty `li` tag. You are setting the height with

`[ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' }"`

which add a raw inline style in pixel.

To fix that, you can either rework your accordion to make it a bit more clear and simpler (using an existing component for that maybe, because yours seems really complicated for something this simple), or working with another property than the height like `display` :

```
[ngStyle]="{display: menu.active ? 'initial' : 'none'}"
```

And rework the style and animation to your needs.